# How to make a textAlign center in a paragraph

Tags: react-native

I have some text paragraph like this:

```
<Text>
    <Text>1111</Text>
    <Text>2222</Text>
    <Text style={{textAlign:"center"}}>
        <Text>3333</Text>
    </Text>
    <Text>4444</Text>
    <Text>5555</Text>
</Text>
```

It shows like:

```
11112222333344445555
```

While I want it to show like:

```
11112222
       3333
44445555
```

in which 3333 is textAlign Center

how can I do this?

I tried to set flexDirection, but it did not work.

---

The data stuct is a little complicated, such as

```
{
    { text : 'aaaa'}
    { text: [
        {
            text: [
                { text: 'bbbb' },
                { text: 'cccc', style:'bold' },
                {
                    text : '3333',
                    style: 'center'
                },
                { text: 'dddd'},
            ], style: 'bold'
        },
        { text: 'eeee' }
    ]},
    { text: 'ffff', style:'i' },
    { text: 'gggg' }
}
```

Because View Component cannot be nested in Text Component, so I can not change the Text wrapped 3333 to View.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: 3333 is centering, while others show textAlign:left

Answer (score 1):

Use a `View` component as a container then wrap the items you want inline in a Text component. [example here](http://dabbott.github.io/react-native-web-player/#code=import%20React%2C%20%7B%20Component%20%7D%20from%20'react'%3B%0Aimport%20%7B%20View%2C%20AppRegistry%2C%20Text%20%7D%20from%20'react-native'%3B%0A%0Aexport%20default%20class%20TextInANest%20extends%20Component%20%7B%0A%20%20render()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CView%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctext%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CText%3E1111%3C%2FText%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CText%3E2222%3C%2FText%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftext%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CText%20style%3D%7B%7BtextAlign%3A%22center%22%7D%7D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CText%3E3333%3C%2FText%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FText%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctext%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CText%3E4444%3C%2FText%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CText%3E5555%3C%2FText%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftext%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FView%3E%0A%20%20%20%20)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20skip%20this%20line%20if%20using%20Create%20React%20Native%20App%0AAppRegistry.registerComponent('TextInANest'%2C%20()%20%3D%3E%20TextInANest)%3B%0A)

Edit 1:

estructure exampe:

```
<View>
  <text>
    <Text>1111</Text>
    <Text>2222</Text>
  </text>
  <Text style={{textAlign:"center"}}>
    <Text>3333</Text>
  </Text>
  <text>
    <Text>4444</Text>
    <Text>5555</Text>
  </text>
</View>
```

[working example here](http://dabbott.github.io/react-native-web-player/#code=import%20React%2C%20%7B%20Component%20%7D%20from%20'react'%3B%0Aimport%20%7B%20View%2C%20AppRegistry%2C%20Text%20%7D%20from%20'react-native'%3B%0A%0Aexport%20default%20class%20TextInANest%20extends%20Component%20%7B%0A%20%20render()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CView%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctext%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CText%3E1111%3C%2FText%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CText%3E2222%3C%2FText%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftext%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CText%20style%3D%7B%7BtextAlign%3A%22center%22%7D%7D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CText%3E3333%3C%2FText%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FText%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctext%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CText%3E4444%3C%2FText%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CText%3E5555%3C%2FText%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftext%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FView%3E%0A%20%20%20%20)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20skip%20this%20line%20if%20using%20Create%20React%20Native%20App%0AAppRegistry.registerComponent('TextInANest'%2C%20()%20%3D%3E%20TextInANest)%3B%0A)

Comment: But may be the text which need to be centering is nested in another Text Compent. Change it to view will lead to an error.

Comment: did you check the example?

Comment: the example worked, while the text compnents is directly in a View component. 
but I am trying to show a paragraph posting by a user. The text which need to be centring may be nested deep in the text structure, see the example I add below my question. The structure maybe more complicated.

Comment: according to the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html#containers) you will need to use View component otherwise you will not be able to accomplish that

Answer (score 0):

You can use View as I mentioned here.

```
  <View style={{alignItems:'flex-start'}}>
    <Text>111111</Text>
  </View>
  <View style={{alignItems:'center'}}>
  <Text>2222222</Text>
  </View>
  <View style={{alignItems:'flex-start'}}>
  <Text>333333</Text>
  </View>
```

Comment: But may be the text which need to be centering is nested in another Text Compent. Change it to view will lead to an error.

Comment: Yes, why not? Only put the nested text component inside of a View and change its style.

Comment: That means I need to change all the parents compent to View, and wrap many  text components in another Text component. See the stuct I added in my question.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
<Text>
    <Text>1111</Text>
    <Text>2222</Text>
    <Text style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <Text>3333</Text>
    </Text>
    <Text>4444</Text>
    <Text>5555</Text>
</Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is working for me

```
<View style={{ width: '100%', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
    <Text style={{ width: '100%' }}>1111</Text>
    <Text style={{ width: '100%' }}>2222</Text>
    <Text style={{ textAlign: "center", width: '100%' }}>
        <Text>3333</Text>
    </Text>
    <Text style={{ width: '100%' }}>4444</Text>
    <Text style={{ width: '100%' }}>5555</Text>
</View>
```